# Salesforce LWC Pass variables from parent to child and use them in .js dynamically without hard coding field

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a generic LWC component that provides a lightning-datatable. This component has an attribute `@api compareThis = ''`.

This LWC component is child to a Aura Component. So from Aura component I pass `compareThis = "Length__c"`.

Now in the LWC datatable component, I have an `oncellchange` action in which I am supposed to compare `compareThis` attribute with a number.

The code to compare is `event.detail.draftValues[0].Length__c > 30`. 
If you notice , this is hardcoding of the fieldname.

I am unable to use `event.detail.draftValues[0].this.compareThis`  or `event.detail.draftValues[0].compareThis` .

Is there a way I can ignore hardcoding fieldname while using `event.detail.draftValues[i].`?

Comment: Rishabh, Please format your question.

Comment: format how? sorry i am new here and this was my first post

Answer (score 2):

in JavaScript you can retrieve object's property using this syntax:

```
event.detail.draftValues[0][this.compareThis]
```

Comment: Does not work with that as well.
Here is from console

Didnot work @Christian .
t.detail.draftValues[0]["WOD_2__Policy_Definition__Months_Covered"]
"27"

t.detail.draftValues[0].WOD_2__Policy_Definition__Months_Covered
"27"

this.compareWith
"WOD_2__Policy_Definition__Type"

t.detail.draftValues[0][this.compareWith]
undefined

Comment: is "WOD_2__Policy_Definition__Months_Covered" a custom field?

Comment: yes it is a custom field

Comment: sholdn't be "WOD_2__Policy_Definition__Months_Covered__c"?

Comment: no, its not that way, if you see the console log that i pasted above, its never __c. this is the way data is formed

Comment: can you post a JSON of event.detail.draftValues[0], please?